# Generalized Ising Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-physics, ising-model, thermodynamic-formalism

I am in very trouble with a particular expression. I leave the original pages in order to have everything available and what I am goin to leave are the first pages of nine chapter of Non Perturbative Renormalization by Vieri Mastropietro. My problem is: how can I find the expression (9.48)? I can't remove the sum over σ when I derive with respect of $\beta J$ the partition function $Z_I$ in the r.h.s. of (9.48) to get "one" exponential as the l.h.s. .

I skipped the section 9.2 because is off topic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the $Z_I$ in eq. 9.48 is not the $Z$ in equation 9.47.

Comment: Thank you @CarloBeenakker for your answer. Yes, I simply consider $Z_I$ as in (9.2) but with $J$ that depends on sites. What $Z_I$ would you consider to get (9.48)?

Comment: You are taking derivative with respect to a specific J, which is site dependent. So you have to check in equation (9.2) what are the quantities that are multiplying this particular J. It will be the pair of sigmas that are on the left hand side of (9.48)

Comment: Thank you @thedude. Of course is true what you said.But $Z_I$ is a sum all over the possible configuration $\sigma$, that is the (9.2). So what I get if I derive $Z_I$ is something like $\sum_{\sigma} \sigma_{x,x_0} \sigma_{x+1,x_0} e^{-\beta H[J]} $. How can I kill the $\sum_{\sigma}$ ?